# Unable to locate metadata for identity provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, shibboleth, opensaml

I'm trying to configure both Shibboleth service provider and identity provider on localhost for testing purposes.

The problem is that I'm getting "unable to locate metadata for identity provider" error when trying to access a protected resource.

I've already read all tutorials and discussions that are related to software configuration and this particular error fixing, but nothing works for me.

shibboleth2.xml config for SP:

```
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
xmlns:conf="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"    
xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
clockSkew="180">

<InProcess logger="native.logger">
    <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true">
        <Site id="1" name="localhost" />
    </ISAPI>
</InProcess>

<TCPListener address="127.0.0.1" port="1600" acl="127.0.0.1" />

<StorageService type="Memory" id="mem" cleanupInterval="900" /> 
<SessionCache type="StorageService" StorageService="mem" cacheAssertions="false" cacheAllowance="900" inprocTimeout="900" cleanupInterval="900" /> 
<ReplayCache StorageService="mem" /> 
<ArtifactMap artifactTTL="180" /> 

<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap>
        <Host name="localhost">
            <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
        </Host>
    </RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>

<ApplicationDefaults  id="default" policyId="default"
    entityID="http://localhost/secure"
    homeURL="http://localhost/secure"
    signing="false" encryption="false"
    REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id">

    <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" relayState="ss:mem" handlerURL="/Shibboleth.sso"
              checkAddress="false" handlerSSL="false" cookieProps="http">
        <SSO entityID="https://bios-hp/idp/shibboleth">
          SAML2 SAML1
        </SSO>

        <Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>

        <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="false"/>
        <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1 ::1"/>
        <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="false"/>
        <Handler type="DiscoveryFeed" Location="/DiscoFeed"/>

        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/POST" index="1"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign" index="2"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/Artifact" index="3"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/ECP" index="4"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:PAOS"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML/POST" index="5"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML/Artifact" index="6"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01"/>

        <LogoutInitiator type="Local" Location="/SLO/Logout"/>

        <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/SOAP"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/Redirect" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/POST" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/Artifact" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>

        <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/SOAP"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>
        <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/Redirect" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
        <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/POST" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
        <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/Artifact" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>

        <md:ArtifactResolutionService Location="/Artifact/SOAP" index="1"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>
    </Sessions>

    <Errors supportContact="root@localhost"
        helpLocation="/about.html"
        styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>

    <MetadataProvider type="XML" file="C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/idp.metadata.xml"/>

    <AttributeExtractor type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="attribute-map.xml"/>

    <AttributeResolver type="Query" subjectMatch="true"/>

    <AttributeFilter type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-policy.xml"/>

    <CredentialResolver type="File" key="sp-key.pem" certificate="sp-cert.pem"/>
</ApplicationDefaults>

<SecurityPolicyProvider type="XML" validate="true" path="security-policy.xml"/>

<ProtocolProvider type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="protocols.xml"/>
```

idp.metadata.xml references by SP config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://bios-hp/idp/shibboleth" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:shibmd="urn:mace:shibboleth:metadata:1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0 urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><Extensions><shibmd:Scope regexp="false"/></Extensions><KeyDescriptor><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIID...zY=</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></KeyDescriptor><ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding" Location="https://bios-hp:8443/idp/profile/SAML1/SOAP/ArtifactResolution" index="1"/><ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://bios-hp:8443/idp/profile/SAML2/SOAP/ArtifactResolution" index="2"/><NameIDFormat>urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:nameIdentifier</NameIDFormat><NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat><SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:profiles:AuthnRequest" Location="https://bios-hp/idp/profile/Shibboleth/SSO"/><SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://bios-hp/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO"/><SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" Location="https://bios-hp/idp/profile/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign/SSO"/><SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://bios-hp/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO"/></IDPSSODescriptor><AttributeAuthorityDescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><Extensions><shibmd:Scope regexp="false"/></Extensions><KeyDescriptor><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIID...SzY=</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></KeyDescriptor><AttributeService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding" Location="https://bios-hp:8443/idp/profile/SAML1/SOAP/AttributeQuery"/><AttributeService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://bios-hp:8443/idp/profile/SAML2/SOAP/AttributeQuery"/><NameIDFormat>urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:nameIdentifier</NameIDFormat><NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat></AttributeAuthorityDescriptor></EntityDescriptor>
```

Note, that entityID in both files is equal as its the common reason for my error.

The protected site is hosted on local IIS and is accessible via

```
http://bios-hp/secure
```

URL where I get the error.

All possible status URLs for both SP and IdP return successfull results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Don't know about your secured path, but it seems that your entityId is `http://bios-hp/secure`, with a `http` not `https`, so I believe your secured path would be a `http` and shibboleth works with `https`.

Common errors are:

- **EntityId typo**: but that is not your case
- **metadata file path mistake**: but that too is not your case
- **SP configuration in IdP side**: you got to check that, too.